# Overcoming complete separation using Boosted Regression Tree

Tags: machine-learning, regression, glm, cross-validation, gbm

I am attempting to fit and test a model using BRT analysis and I keep running into the error of complete separation. I have attempted multiple ways to overcome this issue to no avail. I utilized a form of penalized regression through logistf, put a Bayesian prior on models, omitted variables I thought were responsible for overfitting, transformed all of my skewed predictor variables using log1p, and ignored it altogether according to Coadou, 2013 (http://www.epj-conferences.org/articles/epjconf/pdf/2013/16/epjconf_sos2012_02004.pdf) suggestions that overfitting in BRT training models wouldn't pose a large problem.

In her article, she states that trees that lead to a perfect fit of the training data are contributing very little to the final boosting output on the testing sample. However, even when I ignore complete separation and attempt to predict to my evaluation data (I am attempting to fit my model to 2000 points, and test it on the remaining 11,141 points) my plot comes up blank (Fig. 2 in Elith et al. 2008).

None of the articles I read discuss solutions to overcome complete separation in BRTs specifically, which makes me think there might be an alternative solution to this problem that I'm unaware of.

I have a very large dataset (13,141 points) with a binary response variable and 16 covariates. I also tried fitting the model using only 5 covariates and ran into the same issue. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the head of my data to give you an idea.

```
Hotspot_Resp Dist_Build Dist_River Dist_Road Dist_Underpro   Aspect
           0        935       1074     18396           335   303.69
           0        893       1112     18355           299   176.50
           0        884       1133     18335           298   176.50
           0        849       1208     18261           297   175.10
           0        856       1216     18254           310   175.10
           0       1212       1501     18021           827   215.54   
Soil_Type OPP_Class    Elevation   Dist_Forest     Build_Density Dist_Fence
        2         1     3.218876     5.659482           9.360116   8.180601
        2         1     2.995732     5.673323           9.360116   8.179480
        2         1     2.995732     5.730100           9.360116   8.174985
        2         1     2.079442     5.908083           9.360116   8.161090
        2         1     2.079442     5.945421           9.360116   8.156797
        2         1     2.564949     6.523562           9.254766   7.988204
      DistGC       Dist_Clear     Slope Canopy_Cov   No_Canopy
    5.424950               0  1.0152307         0            3
    5.204007               0  1.4678743         0            3
    5.117994               0  1.4678743         0            3 
    4.753590               0  1.5748465         0            3
    4.804021               0  1.5748465         0            3
    5.863631               0  0.9895412         0            3
```

Please excuse the noisy variable names! My response variable, 'Hotspot_Resp' is binary; 'Canopy_Cov', 'No_Canopy', 'Soil_Type' and 'OPP_Class' are categorical variables. Many of these variables are log1p or log transformed but for simplicity I kept the original column names here.

No matter what I try, every time I try to fit the following model:

```
gbm.step(data=training.model1, gbm.x=2:16, gbm.y=1, 
                family="bernoulli", tree.complexity=5, learning.rate=0.01, 
                bag.fraction=0.5)
```

It runs the cross-validation process, but I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

*Please note*: One of the first steps according to Elith et al. 2008 tutorial on BRT's is to check the sum of the response variable. The only way I could achieve this was by setting Hotspot_Resp to numeric with a intermediate step of setting it to character. When Hotspot_Resp is set to numeric, I am able to successfully execute fitting the model (albeit with complete separation). However, when I set to factor, I receive the following:

```
Error in while (delta.deviance > tolerance.test & n.fitted < max.trees) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 44 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y.data) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(y.data, site.weights) : '*' not meaningful for factors
```

Once again thank you so much in advance for any help or insight you can provide!!

Comment: What is a ratio of 0 to 1 in Hotspot_Resp attribute? Have you tried to set Hotspot_Resp to factor?

Comment: Hi pplonski, the ration is about 50/50. My training model has 2000 points and 941 points are 1's. This is reflective of the entire dataset. I have tried to set Hotspot_Resp to a factor but the model doesn't run. I think it is OK because I set the family to bernoulli and also identified my response variable. There are more commands in this step that I'm playing with that could be creating the separation but still haven't figured it out... Thank you for your input!